# Javascript: Clicking an injected button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, onclick

when I inject some code the onclick doesn't work
here is the code I use.

```js
 
document.getElementById('headbar').onclick = function() {
var list_div_preleva =  document.getElementsByClassName('preleva_dati').length; 
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('box_commenti');

for(var i = list_div_preleva; i < list.length; i++) {
var parentDiv = list[i].parentNode.id;
var id_post = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
var creaelementodiv = document.createElement("button");
creaelementodiv.className = "preleva_dati";
creaelementodiv.setAttribute("id", "blocco_dati");
creaelementodiv.innerHTML = "<li>preleva il post</li>";
id_post.appendChild(creaelementodiv);
}
};
```

```html
<div id="headbar">div</div>
```

when the code is inside, onclick doesn't work

```html
 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
document.getElementById('blocco_dati').onclick = function() {
alert(11);
};
```

can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('headbar').onclick = function() {




var id_post = document.getElementById("headbar2");
var creaelementodiv = document.createElement("button");
creaelementodiv.className = "preleva_dati";
creaelementodiv.setAttribute("id", "blocco_dati");
creaelementodiv.innerHTML = "preleva il post";
creaelementodiv.setAttribute("onclick", "doSomething();");
id_post.appendChild(creaelementodiv);
};


function doSomething() {
alert(11);
};
```

```html
<div id="headbar">div</div>

<div id="headbar2"></div>
```

You can set one more attribute while injecting element

for ex:

```
creaelementodiv.setAttribute("onclick", "doSomething();");
```

and then you can call that function like

```
function doSomething() {
alert(11);
};
```

Comment: i have already tried, but the result equals onclick, it doesn't work

Comment: i am using a crhome extension, does this change?

Comment: Please check my edited answer it is work in chrome browser too.

Comment: yes it works, but using javascript on developer extensions, it doesn't work, because this happens

Comment: may i know? why u are using developer extension? because the code works here then you can directely run your project in browser.

Comment: I want to create an extension that allows me to get info on another website, for example youtube, extract the link via button to convert it